# If $p(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $\bf A$, how to prove or disprove that $p(\mathbf A)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $λ^n + a_{n-1}λ^{n-1} + ... + a_0$ is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ I have to proof or disprove $\mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}*\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I} = 0$

What is wrong with this proof?

$λ_i^n + a_{n-1}λ_i^{n-1} + ... + a_0 = 0$
with $λ_i$ an eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ with corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v_i}$

From this equation follows the vector equation 
$λ_i^n\mathbf{v_i} + a_{n-1}λ_i^{n-1}\mathbf{v_i} + ... + a_0\mathbf{v_i} = 0$

From the definition of the eigenvalue follows $\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{v_i} + a_{n-1}*\mathbf{A^{n-1}}\mathbf{v_i} + ... + a_0\mathbf{v_i} = 0$

Distribution $(\mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}*\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I})\mathbf{v_i} = 0$

$\mathbf{v_i}$ can't be zero -> $\mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}*\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I} = 0$

Comment: That is the [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: Given that it's the statement of the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem (which is nontrivial to prove), if the problem was given as a HW problem, it's not really fair to the student.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your last step you seem to divide by a vector, which is not allowed.

The *matrix* $M = \mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}*\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I}$ is zero if and only if $Mv = 0$ for all vectors $v$. You proved this only for eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$. If $\mathbf{A}$ had a basis of eigenvectors, your proof would be sufficient, but $\mathbf{A}$ might not have any eigenvectors at all.

Comment: How do you get to "not any eigenvectors at all"? You might not be able to select a full basis of eigenvectors, but since $I,A,...,A^n$ are linearly dependent, there is a minimal polynomial $A^m+...+c_1A+c_0I=0$ , and for any root of the minimal polynomial $(A-\lambda I)$ has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Consider the rotation by e.g. $\pi/2$ in the plane, i.e. $A = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi/2) & -\sin(\pi/2) \\ \sin(\pi/2) & \cos(\pi/2)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
as a map from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself.
Then the characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(x) = x^2 + 1$ and does not have a real root. It is also intuitively clear that a rotation by 90 degrees cannot have an eigenvector, because no vector is just "stretched" by some factor.

Comment: Ok, then this proof method would have to apply to the complexification of the vector space, so that complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors become admissible.

Comment: In the complex case your argument is correct and the characteristic polynomial always has a root and thereby an eigenpair. However, the field might be neither $\mathbb C$ nor $\mathbb R$, so a complexification is not possible in general.

Comment: @iljusch No, it's not correct in the complex case. Yes, in that case $A$ must have an eigenvector, but all  that the argument  proves is that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $p(A)$, which does not (immediately) imply $p(A)=0$. (For example, $0$  is the only complex eigenvalue of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right, of course. My comment was an answer to LutzL's comment, so my words "your argument is correct" were not meant to address the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the field $K$ of scalars is algebraically closed, there may not be an eigenvalue $\lambda_i\in K$.

But even if we assume $K$ *is* algebraically closed (e.g., $K=\mathbb{C}$), there's still an error in your last line.

Assuming $\mathbf{v_i}$ is an eigenvector, the equation
$$
(\mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I})\mathbf{v_i} = 0
$$
doesn't imply that
$$\mathbf{A}^n + a_{n-1}\mathbf{A^{n-1}} + ... + a_0\mathbf{I}=0$$
It only implies that it's singular (i.e., its null space is nonzero).